# atd creating processes with low priority

Tags: linux, centos, process, at

I'm queuing up some long-running PHP processes in `atd` to be run at a later time.

However, when `atd` fires up the process for the task, it keeps creating the tasks as low priority.

I come back to find my task has been paused by the system half way through to make way for more important processes.

How do I change the priority of the processes that `atd` creates?

Comment: Have you considerd `atd`'s `-l` option, which is likely pausing your jobs due to system load? Increase the system load before the jobs are paused, rather than adjusting the job priorities. Most of the time, finding good priorities is not as easy as it seems.

Comment: How do I set this? In centos, it is running as a service. seems to be running as `atd -f`

Comment: I think your question has an answer here: [contos - How and where is the at command configured?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91260/79761)